# Using Foreign Key (FK) as Discriminator for Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

**[Q:] Is it possible to use a FK as a discriminator in EF and what workarounds have people come up with?**

## The scenario

### EF Objects

```
public class List
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List List { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

### Database

The existing DB that **is not used by EF exclusively (i.e. cannot be changed)** has fields as follows:

```
List
    Id         int not null      (identity)
    Name       varchar

ListItem
    Id         int not null      (identity)
    ListId     int not null      (FK to List.Id)
    Text       varchar
```

### The desired outcome

I want the Id of List to be the discriminator for the *ListItem*. i.e. For each entry in list a separate class descended from *ListItem* is implemented.

For example for List [Id:1]

```
public class PersonListItem : ListItem
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class ListItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ListItem>
{
    Map<PersonListItem>(m => m.Requires("ListId").HasValue(1));
}
```

Under the above scenario saving changes results in a SQL exception because EF tries to insert into List_Id when creating a new *ListItem* instance. List_Id is not a field, and I can't map *ListId* as a property on *ListItem* as wouldn't be able to be used as a discriminator.

## My solution so far...

[This Q&A](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/adodotnetentityframework/thread/24380ee6-4753-46a2-a3ed-b1cb2e2d161c) explains why they made the decision not to allow FK as discriminator.

My workaround so far is to add another field to the db to use as a discriminator which is then set to the same value as *ListId* using an insert trigger (to handle non-EF inserts) and then add the *ListId* navigational property to *ListItem* entity.

**Does anyone have any suggestions / alternatives?**

Answer (score 3):

Most easily the solution lies in introducing an enum that is used as discriminator to represent the type. The post you mentioned clearly describes a FK cannot be used so you need to refactor that to something that can be applied. It requires some maintenance but since you also have to know the types that derive from your listitem, I don't see this as a major problem. Other option you have would be to move away from TPH and use TablePerType. That way you don't actualy have to introduce an enum, but you will incurr a table for each derived listitem.

Comment: Thanks for your input Carlo.
I should have mentioned that I discovered that TPT doesn't suffer from the issue, but it's not really an option in my scenario.

Can you elaborate on the Enum approach? How does that let me avoid adding another field to the DB to serve as a discriminator? The other problem is that this not and EF exclusive table, legacy applications still write to it (hence the trigger approach).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming code first EF 4, there is a somewhat (very?) contrived way, that requires using views to create a virtual discriminator column that is the same as ListId.

You need to be capable of adding a view to the DB and "instead of" triggers to that view in order to simulate a new column. In all this you need to go around some problems EF has with this approach.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[vListItem] as 
select Id, ListId,[Text]
,cast(ListId as varchar(10)) as Discriminator  
from xListItem;
GO

Note: need the cast to varchar <= int causes errors on EF (MaxLength facet)
```

An example of trigger for insert would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_vListItem_Insert
ON [vListItem]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
Begin
    -- set nocount on
    Insert into xListItem (ListId,[Text]) 
    Select i.ListId, i.[Text]
    from Inserted i

    -- Need this so Ef knows a row has been inserted
    select Id from xListItem where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and Id = scope_identity()
End

Note: Delete and Update would be similar.
```

Then you can have in your model:

```
public class vListItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ListId")]
    public xList aList { get; set; }
    public int ListId { get; set; }
}

public class vPerson : vListItem
{
}
public class vThing : vListItem
{
}
```

On your DbContext you can have:

```
    public DbSet<vListItem> vitems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<vPerson> vpersons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<vThing> vthings { get; set; }
```

And, OnModelCreating you define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<vListItem>()
    .Map<vPerson>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("1"))
    .Map<vThing>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("2"))
    ;
```

Thats, it. Some tests:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodPersonInsert()
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        xList xl = db.lists.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
        vPerson vp = new vPerson();
        vp.Text = "p4";
        vp.aList = xl;
        db.vpersons.Add(vp);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodThingInsert()
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        xList xl = db.lists.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);
        vThing vt = new vThing();
        vt.Text = "t0";
        vt.aList = xl;
        db.vthings.Add(vt);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple mappings. But, the core of the issue is to not have this type of relationship at all and revisit your design.